# to have or to not have multiple categories

Tags: e-commerce, shopping-cart, categorization, organization, visitors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Including unique content under multiple navigation trees](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/8684/including-unique-content-under-multiple-navigation-trees)

It's simple - how visitors respond to **one product/item placed in multiple categories**? Is it considered as benefit or as WTF?

To me, it looks like "hack" - instead of defining/refactoring clear categories, I just place product into multiple existing ones. Which could be great for site admin, but I'm really interested only in visitors.

Sure, there are cases, when it makes sense - like categories+manufacturers subcategories, but then it's not category in common sense but rather "filter".

I'm really not convinced about this one. This particular scenario is about **shopping**, but it probably could apply to other areas as well.

Comment: Try this link  http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/8684/including-unique-content-under-multiple-navigation-trees

Comment: See also: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/8684/including-unique-content-under-multiple-navigation-trees, where the option to say 'also found under' suggests that the website *knows it's there twice* but is clearly trying to help the user, rather than letting the user come to their own conclusion about the apparent redundancy or duplication. Apart from anything else it's beneficial to the site because it increase the chances of cross linking between product lists. Plus if content management team are having trouble deciding - then why NOT put in multiple categories?

Comment: thx for that, another thing to think about. would this apply also for mobile version where space matters? I mean, breadcrumbs could be "too expensive". Plus there's another (subjective) problem with multiple categories, they tend to result in complex hiearchies making decisions really hard. One-category per item could enforce "keeping navigation simple". Yes, it's probably impossible to avoid this in general, but it could help.